# ValueError: too many values to unpack - OpenCV Python HoughLines

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I am trying t get rho and theta from a line detected in an image thanks to HoughLine from OpenCV.

```
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, hThreshold, maxLineGap=lineGap)
if lines is not None:
    for line in lines:
       rho, theta = line[0]
```

But I get this error for the last line.

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Do you know how to resolve this? Or another way of getting rho and theta values?

*PS: I installed opencv-python with pip3 install opencv-python --user*

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial for [hough line transform](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line[0]` in the above code is a list containing 4 values. That's why, you are getting above error. What you are doing is trying to detect lines using `Probabilistic Hough lines`, i.e.,

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(binarized image, ro accuracy, theta accurancy, threshold, minimum line length, max line gap)
```

**correct code:**

```
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, hThreshold, maxLineGap=lineGap)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
```

But, what you want to do is line detection using `Hough lines`. So, change your code from `lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, hThreshold, maxLineGap=lineGap)` to

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 220)
for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    print(rho, theta)
```

Comment: Indeed it works perfectly with the HoughLines method, thank you for the quick answer.